# How can I do ASP.NET MVC view scaffolding in Rider IDE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, rider

Currently trying Rider (JetBrains IDE for .Net). I used to work on Visual Studio Enterprise for c# asp.net MVC projects, and i'd like to know if there's a way (on Rider) to do like the "Add -> view -> with create/delete/update/list" feature on Visual Studio?

Something which would generate CRUD views like that :

```
@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Warrior>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Health)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Health)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

PS : if there's a way to do it with controllers to... :D

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062951/scaffolding-controller-in-rider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can vote\track this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-12363

Comment: Thanks for the track link, i'll keep an eye on it! :)

Answer (score 12):

### But you still can...

You can use  `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` terminal tool. which is used for generating **controllers** and **views** with different options.

Install the tool globally.

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name MyNewController -m MyModel -dc MyDbContext -outDir Controllers/`

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and is unfortunately [not a feature in Rider](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000556344-Scaffolding-controller-in-Rider). I couldn't tell you if it's a planned feature, but I hope so.
My only suggestion might be to open VS, scaffold, and then use Rider again to continue coding.

Comment: Well, thanks for the "scaffolding" word I didn't knew. Your solution may be one solution (not sure if it's the optimal solution but .. meh, why not xD) or i'll wait till JetBrains implements it in Rider...

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah I hope they implement it too :)